# Access WildFly10 with JMX fails

Tags: wildfly, jmx, wildfly-10

I'm trying to acces a virtualbox machine with a WildFly10 via JMX from my local machine. In the JConsole I'm using the following parameters:

```
remote process: service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://172.28.128.3:9990
username: test
password: test
```

Both username and password works, because I can acces WildFly with that username/password on `172.28.128.3:9990`

The message is the following:

> Secure connection failed. Retry insecurely?

If i click yes, then this appears:

> Connection failed: Retry?

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I've seen that if I execute Jconsole.exe -debug I can see this error at the connection time:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: http-remoting-jmx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client.jar` in the JConsole class path:

```
 [steve@steves-mbp wildfly-10.1.0.Final]$ jconsole \
  -J-Djava.class.path=$JAVA_HOME/lib/jconsole.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client.jar
```

Your `service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://172.28.128.3:9990` URL will then work, or at least something similar did it for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was using jconsole from JDK, now with jconsole from Wildfly it works, no jar includes needed.