# Xymon JMX Monitor

Tags: wildfly, monitor, hobbitmon

I am struggling to get JMX monitoring on WildFly 10. The current utility is able to do so for both JBoss 4.2.1 as well as WildFly 10 (jmxstat for xymon). However, when I try to replicate production configuration in a sandbox, WildFly crashes until I start reverting changes to JAVA_OPT definitions in the standalone.conf file. I was referred to the standalone.xml file, but nothing I have there makes any difference.

Furthermore, I tried having jmxstat communicate with WildFly via port 9990 (as opposed to port 64850, which works in current production). No luck. I even tried modifying the jmxstat shell script, but that failed as well. I've exhausted all current means of troubleshooting and don't know how to move forward.

Lastly, to add unbelievable insult to injury, the log file for jmxstat is no help whatsoever and WildFly doesn't give any indications either (e.g. not even a connection refused error in server.log file). If there is a better way to monitor WildFly and report to xymon, I'm all ears. Otherwise I need to figure out how to get this working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acces WildFly10 with JMX fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886906/acces-wildfly10-with-jmx-fails)

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe. xymon will need to be set up the same way as jconsole in the indicated answer

Comment: Not sure I would see this as a dupe since JMXstat does not use jconsole to poll unless I am missing something (I do not have, nor do I have experience reading, the source code for the jar client).

Comment: I do not mean not jconsole itself - I am pointing out how it needs to be set up to communicate with the WildFly JMX beans. JMXStat will need to be set up the same way - put the client jar in the classpath; use the JBoss URL format, etc.